# Calling var using .addclass causing split second blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to change the content on the page, however as you can see on http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk it causes a blank space for split second as one class fades out and another comes in. Is there a better way to call the new class over the top of the old one then fadeout the one below or something that doesn't cause the same issue?

Sorry if its a silly question but JQuery isn't my strong point.

```
var Monday = "<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-top\">Mondays at NG1 Club<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-bottom\">Monday<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>#######<\/p><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-link\" href=\"#\">Book Online<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http:\/\/ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/02\/testwhatson1.jpg\" alt=\"Monday\">";
            var Tuesday = "<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-top\">Tuesdays at NG1 Club<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-bottom\">Tuesday<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>#######<\/p><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-link\" href=\"#\">Book Online<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http:\/\/ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/02\/testwhatson1.jpg\" alt=\"Tuesday\">";
            var Wednesday = "<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-top\">Wednesdays at NG1 Club<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-bottom\">#Midweek Madness<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>#######<\/p><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-link\" href=\"#\">Book Online<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http:\/\/ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/02\/testwhatson1.jpg\" alt=\"#Midweek Madness\">";
            var Thursday = "<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-top\">Thursdays at NG1 Club<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-bottom\">Thursday<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>#######<\/p><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-link\" href=\"#\">Book Online<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http:\/\/ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/02\/testwhatson1.jpg\" alt=\"Thursday\">";
            var Friday = "<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-top\">Fridays at NG1 Club<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-bottom\">Friday<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>#######<\/p><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-link\" href=\"#\">Book Online<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http:\/\/ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/02\/testwhatson1.jpg\" alt=\"Friday\"><\/img>";
            var Saturday = "<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-top\">Saturdays at NG1 Club<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-bottom\">Saturday<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>#######<\/p><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-link\" href=\"#\">Book Online<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http:\/\/ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/02\/testwhatson1.jpg\" alt=\"Saturday\">";
            var Sunday = "<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-top\">Sundays at NG1 Club<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-header-bottom\">Sunday<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>#######<\/p><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span><span>#######<\/span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"ng1_widget_event-text-link\" href=\"#\">Book Online<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http:\/\/ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/02\/testwhatson1.jpg\" alt=\"Sunday\">";

            jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

                $('.ng1_widget_event_nights ul li a').click( function(e) {
                    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
                    event.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from bubbling
                    $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
                });

                $( ".mon_click" ).click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Monday).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $( ".tue_click" ).click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Tuesday).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $( ".wed_click" ).click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Wednesday).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $( ".thu_click" ).click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Thursday).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $( ".fri_click" ).click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Friday).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $( ".sat_click" ).click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Saturday).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $( ".sun_click" ).click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Sunday).fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
```

EDIT:

```
<div class="ng1_widget_event"><ul>
<li class="Monday">
<span>Text</span>
<img src="http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/poptastic1.jpg" alt="Monday">
</li>
<li class="Tuesday">
<span>Text</span>
<img src="http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/poptastic1.jpg" alt="Tuesday">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolutely positioned divs in the same position, all transparent (with opacity: 0;) but the one that is visible, which has opacity 1. 
On the trigger start a timer that simoultaneously raises the opacity of the item to make visible and lowers the opacity of the item to fade out, until the opacity is as needed.

```
function switchDiv(fadeInDiv, fadeOutDiv) {
    if (fadeInDiv.style.opacity == 1) return;
    fadeInDiv.style.opacity = fadeInDiv.style.opacity+0.1;
    fadeOutDiv.style.opacity = fadeOutDiv.style.opacity-0.1;
    setTimeout(fade(fadeInDiv, fadeOutDiv), 500/*this indicates speed, the highest the slowest*/;
}
```

Couldn't test it though, almost time for bed!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help I have now made it so now its in the edited structure: How would I call this on each button?

Comment: You need to bind this function to an event that happens on your button, for example a click or dblclick, using addEventListener function. You can bind each event with a different listener, but it is not good; better delegate to parent nodes and  there check event.source to get the source of the event (the specific button that generated the event). Also, you need to fund current shown element to feed into fadeoutdiv argument, whereas fadeindiv argument will be the element to make visible

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation but thats far to complex for me to take in as my javascript knowledge is limited. But once again thank you for the effort you've gone to